# How to enable/disable button on basis of checking null validation of dynamic row using class?

Tags: jquery

I want to create a row with individual field null validation on which basis the addrow button is enabled and disabled until the total null row checking is being completed, but only the first cell's validation is going on whereas other cells does not invoked the code.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#addrow', function () {

    var flag=0;
     $("#myTable tr").each(function(){

        if ( $( this ).find( "td .required" ).length == 0) 
        {
            $(this).next('td .required').focus();
            alert( $('td .required').next().attr('id'));
             alert('length=0');
             $("#addrow").attr("disabled", true);
             $('td .required').css('background','yellow');
             $('td .required').val("Please Enter Here");
        }
        else
        {
            if($('td .required').val()=='Please Enter Here')
            {
                alert('Please Enter Here');
                $("#addrow").attr("disabled", true);
            }
            else
            {
                alert('enabled');
                flag=1;
            }   
        }
        });
        $(document).on('click', 'td .required', function() {   
        if($(this).val()=='Please Enter Here') {
            $(this).css('background','white');
            $(this).val('');
            flag=1;
            $("#addrow").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        });

    if(flag==1)
    {
        $("#addrow").removeAttr("disabled");
        var $tr = $('<tr class="prototype" id="row"> <td align="center" ><input type="text" size="10" name="grnno" id="grnno"  class="required" align="right" onblur="return grn_check()"/></td><td align="center" ><input type="text" name="paymentdate  size="10" class="datepicker" align="right" /></td><td align="center"><select id="bankname" name="bankname" class="required"><option value="">Select Bank Name</option><option value="SBI">SBI</option><option value="UBI">UBI</option><option value="UCO">UCO</option><option value="HDFC">HDFC</option></select></td><td align="center" ><input type="text" name="amount[' + count + ']" id="amount[' + count + ']" size="10" class="required" align="right"/></td><td align="center"><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td><td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="id[]" value="' + count + '" class="id" /></td></tr>').appendTo('#myTable tbody');

          $tr.find(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                 changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        count++; 
        flag=0;
    }

});
```

});
**my table has one static row and dynamic row created by add row button including null validation in both static and dynamic row**

Comment: I can't fetch the next row still now

Comment: You should really post a minimal example, so it's easier to read the code & spot any problems. Right now half the code you posted is commented out, and it seems to me that the other half is a lot more complicated than it needs to be in order to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Is it ok right now? Actually I am contantly trying to solve the problem that's why.